# Why JavaScript doesn't work on localhost but works perfectly on my machine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, server, xampp

I'm trying to create a button that hide/show a div, this code work perfectly in my browser, but if I upload to my localhost it make a mess (I use XAMPP)

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

function Mostrar() {
  dropdown.style.display = "flex";
}

function Ocultar() {
  dropdown.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <title>Menu Responsive</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" value="Hide text" onclick="Ocultar()">
  <input type="button" value="Show text" onclick="Mostrar()">
  <ul id="dropdown">
    <li>INICIO</li>
    <li>BLOGS</li>
    <li>CURSOS</li>
    <li>CONTACTO</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your function as below

```
function Mostrar() {
  // dropdown.style.display = "flex"; // Change this to "block"
  dropdown.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of browser issue. Change your Monstrar function into this

```
function Mostrar() {
   dropdown.style.display = "inline-flex";
}
```